# Datatables Auto Filtering Based on Users Entry Point

Tags: php, html, search, datatables, filtering

The current setup on our site allows a user to click a drop down on the homepage and select a city. When a city is selected it auto redirects to that given page. (ex: /oakland, /san-francisco)

Instead of having each user to go a certain page, we are looking into using datatables and having a single page called "/search"

I wanted to know if it is possible to have the datatable filter automatically based on which page the user wanted to view.

For example: customer clicks on drop down on homepage and selects "San Francisco" and it redirects to a /search page which has all the cities listed.

Is it possible to have the datatable see that the user was searching for locations within San Francisco and start the "/search" page only showing those locations that pertain to that city?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

You can use the [fnFilter](http://datatables.net/api) function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  oTable.fnFilter( 'test' );
});
```

This will search and filter on all occurrences of `test`.

You can search for `test` only in a specific row like this:

```
oTable.fnFilter( 'test string', columnIndex );
```

PS: Column index is 0 based

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is this assuming multiple datatables (ie: datatable for san francico, oakland, etc.) or one datatable with all entries and then having it filter based on the link the user clicked? I was able to get this work but only running multiple datatables. Trying to accomplish this with just one

Comment: the filtering is for the table with id= example

Comment: In your case if the column that contains the city is the first one, and you want to filter results for `Nicosia` then you can use  `oTable.fnFilter( 'Nicosia', 0 ); ` after the table initialisation as shown above